# Plugin javascript ou jquery estrelinhas

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mysql, ajax

Obs:

> *Não sei se pode fazer está pergunta aqui, caso não! Favor desconsiderar/deletar.*

Alguém conhece algum plugin que eu possa fazer essa tela(a classificação):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde está classificação estou tentando fazer, encontrei esse [plugin](http://www.myjqueryplugins.com/jquery-plugin/jrating) e estou lendo a documentação dele pra ver se consigo, se alguém souber de algum que possa fazer esse serviço e puder me indicar.

Esta classificação será assim haverá 120 estrelinhas cinza claro quando passado o mouse ou o dedo(em caso de tablets e celulares), ou onde tem a setinha pra cima e pra baixo aumenta e diminui a quantidade se estrelinhas, elas vão acendendo e e fazendo o insersão no banco e retonando simultaneamente(vou tentar fazer isso com ajax). Seria mais ou menos um sisteminha de votação.

Comment: JB, perguntas de *recomendação* são um assunto que geralmente não combina com o formato de perguntas e respostas objetivas do Stack Overflow. [Houve já discussão sobre isso](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/57/devemos-aceitar-quest%C3%B5es-de-recomenda%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Por isso, a comunidade fechou a pergunta por achar que não se encaixa no escopo do site. No entanto, fique à vontade para fazer novas perguntas, principalmente se forem específicas sobre programação. Sugiro que leia sobre [ask]. Abraço!

Comment: ok. Obrigado e desculpas.